# Problem changing values in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Simplifying
I have a text box and a button
The button just create an messagebox with the text from the textbox.
But i change the value of the textbox, the new value apears (Ex: Type 123) but the message box does not show the value.

If i try to use the value in the programming (get the value by textbox1.text) the variable has nothing ( textbox1.text = "") but i can still see what i typed in the form.

Anyone has any clue?

Comment: are you sure you have the right text box? sometimes textbox1 and textbox11 look the same when you have a lot ( insert nag about proper naming here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Eric and Crippledsmurf. As both of you said, its hard to help without the code.
The problem I found is that when calling the form, I send some objects by reference, so I can track them down and I found that when (don't ask me why it happens that way, I'm still working on it) the construtor is called he make an new component, so the component in the interface no longer represents the one pointed by the variable "textbox1" (Yes Crash893, I haven't mispelled the name).

I found that I was making some mess with the references, and probably that was causing the problem. I fixed the problem by changing the actions performed by references for delegates and events, but I couldn't track down the exactly source of the problem.

Thanks, again, everyone for the insights.

Answer (score 0):

Your button's click event handler should look something like this

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
}
```

I suspect you already have code similar to this and that at some point the textbox is cleared or otherwise set to String.Emppty but without seeing actual code it is difficult to help you

Comment: Its exaclty what i'm doing. I'll go check the others functions to see if there is anyone cleaning the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

When/where did you check the value of textBox1.Text? If you're checking it in the constructor, Form1_Load, or anything else that occurs *before* you'll have typed text, you will get an empty value.

To properly check the value of textBox1.Text, you should set what's called a breakpoint on the line that calls MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text). To do this, click in the grey area of the source editor (it's on the far left) on the line containing MessageBox.Show(..). A red circle will appear and your code should be highlighted. When you run your application and click on your button, your application should pause and Visual Studio will highlight that line and from here you can hover over "textBox1.Text" in the MessageBox.Show() line and it should show you the current value.

If your application is as simple as a form, a textbox, and your button1_Clicked event handling code, this should work no problem. If it is not this simple, then you need to look for anything that sets the value of the textBox in your code and make sure it isn't passing any blank values by using breakpoints.

To solve this properly, though, we really need more information.